# setting up home ftp server using filezilla

Tags: ftp

I googled, followed all the instructions but still stuck, and unable to create a home ftp server.

My internet is from dsl modem -> vonage router -> wifi router

FileZilla server ip is 127.0.0.1 and it works fine when tried from command prompt. But I need it to be accessible from outside.

I enabled ftp on wifi router's web settings page using virtual server setting.

I am stuck at this point, I don't know what else to do further. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is an internal IP not to be used outside your machine. Are you trying to set up a public facing FTP server? or only internal to your home network?

Comment: I am trying to set up a public ftp which I can use from anywhere in the world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pretty much summarizes your needs(via lifehacker.com)

> If you're FTP'ing across your home
>   network (like from your upstairs PC to
>   your bedroom PC), you can reach the
>   server by using its internal network
>   address (most likely something like
>   192.168.xx.xx.) From the command line, type ipconfig to see what that address
>   is. If you want to log into your FTP
>   server over the internet, set up a
>   memorable URL for it and allow
>   connections from outside your network.
>   To do so, check out how to assign a
>   domain name to your home server and
>   how to access your home server behind
>   a router and firewall.

[Original Article](http://lifehacker.com/339887/build-a-home-ftp-server-with-filezilla)

[How to assign a domain name to your home server](http://lifehacker.com/software/web-publishing/geek-to-live--how-to-assign-a-domain-name-to-your-home-web-server-124804.php)

[How to access a server behind a router and firewall](http://lifehacker.com/software/top/geek-to-live--how-to-access-a-home-server-behind-a-routerfirewall-127276.php)

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you are planning on accessing your server remotely, (not in your network) you will have to enable port forwarding on your router. (Use the ip address of the machine running the server and use port 21) Otherwise, you only be able to connect while in your LAN.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to access your internal network from the internet. Consider using a service like [dynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/dyndns/) if your router supports it.